# pass one command to another one on the terminal

Tags: awk, terminal, grep

Look at the below code

```
awk '{print $1}' grep _Y myFile
```

I want to pass the result of  `grep _Y myFile` to awk command . How to write that line correctly .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not do all in one go:

```
awk '/_y/ {print $1}' myFile
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe `<()` would work?

It sends the output of a command to another command as a file.

I.e. `awk '{print $1}' <(grep _Y myFile)`

Also great for use with `diff`

See [this](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Use pipe `|` symbol to redirect the output of prceeding command to the following command,

```
grep _Y myFile | awk '{print $1}'
```

Comment: +1 And in this specific case OP can use just  awk: `awk '/_Y/{print $1}' myFile`